# How to represent bitfileds in UML

Tags: uml, bit-fields

I am creating a structure of bitfields members as below:

```
struct Param
{
  char move1: 1;
  char move2: 1;
  char move3: 1;
  char move4: 1;
};
```

Can anybody help how to represent them as UML diagram

Comment: For what purpose? In which context?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unfortunately really close to the implementation and language specific. There is no such thing in the OMG UML standard.

Fortunately the UML is quite extensible and you can apply a custom **stereotype** to your fields E.G. `<<bitfield>>` and potentially tweak a code generator to generate bitfields.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `BitField` Primitive declared to be one bit wide. UML then allows you to order properties to keep them in the right sequence. You can even make a `Param` DataType that has your four named properties of type BitField.

If you're generating code, obviously the code generator has to know what to do.